# Can the existence of antiderivative in complex plane implies the function is differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, complex-integration

In complex plane if a function is differentiable once, it is differentiable infinitely many times. So does that mean if a function has an antiderivative in a domain of complex plane then the function is always differentiable in that domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this known as the [theorem of Morera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)